# When the Kafka consumer group will be set to DEAD?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If the consumers within the consumer group stop consuming messages and committing offsets, when will this consumer group be set to DEAD state and removed from broker?

Answer (score 0):

if the consumer thread exceeded `max.poll.interval.ms` between calling `poll` method, check this [link](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#ak-consumer-configuration) for more details.